# ImportError: Cannot load specified object - psycopg2

Tags: python, python-2.7, psycopg2, postgresql-9.2

OpenBSD, PostgreSQL9.2, python2.7
Trying to import psycopg2 module from python command line:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  3 2012, 05:33:56)
[GCC 4.2.1 20070719 ] on openbsd5
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: Cannot load specified object
```

psycopg2 is compiled and installed. I saw _psycopg.so in /site-packages/psycopg2 folder. Maybe he can not see this library ?

Comment: Are you sure this is importable from psycopg2: BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID ? What is ROWID?

Comment: @MikedeKlerk: Parts of the `psycopg2` library; the last line of the traceback is the python module trying to import the C extension. The fact that that is not importable is the *reason* for this question, the library is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `psycopg2` python module includes an extension written in C. That extension cannot be loaded, because another C library that it is depending on is missing.

Check that you still have the PostgreSQL client libraries installed, and that `psycopg2` can find it.

Note that if you run Django in a WSGI server, you need to have set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable *before the WSGI server starts*. Alternatively, recompile the `psycopg2` extension with `LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/lib` to 'hardcode' the path to the PostgreSQL client library at linking time, removing the need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

A last resort would be to add the `/usr/local/pgsql/lib` path to `/etc/ld.so.conf`, see the [`ld.so(8)` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig).

Comment: It was the pointer to libraries (LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/lib). Python command line now import psycopg2 and setting up connection. Django is still writing same error.

Comment: @dima.h: are you using a WSGI server to run Django?

Comment: LD_RUN_PATH does not help. Is there a library paths to libraries in Django environment ?

Comment: @dima.h: one last option added for you.

Comment: ldconfig OpenBSD differs from Linux packages. It works. Thank you )